# Find a function that's convolution with itself is a given function

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-analysis, convolution

I would like to solve this equation for $f(x)$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z)f(t-z) dz = g(t).
$$

Are there any *standard* ways to solve such problems? $g(t)$ can be assumed to be continuous, but may be non-differentiable in a countably many number of points.

Comment: Starting from $ f*f=g $, I think you can take the Fourier transform of both sides. Convolution in the time domain corresponds to pointwise multiplication in the frequency domain.